# How to pass ejs variable to javascript file

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, express

I want to send some ejs variable to my route but I want to have access to this variable in the `.js` file for that html template. I know that using `JSON.stringify(variable)` gives you access to it but it only lets me call that variable with script tags in my html file.

I don't want that but instead want access to this variable in my `.js` file. I've looked at other similar questions but haven't been successful in finding an answer.

Comment: Are you confused about the difference between client side and server side values?

Comment: I want to pass my server variable to the client side javascript. How do I do this?

Comment: With AJAX. You'll have to make a client-side xhr or fetch and configure your server to respond appropriately just like you would with any server side language. How to do that is beyond the scope of an SO answer, just google how to do it there are a million tutorials. The fact that you're running js on both client and server unfortunately doesn't let you escape the problem.